# Package cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, package

I'm using Android to create an App Studio Android. To create it'm using a framework: Cordova.
The problem comes when I go to load the application on the USB device. In "All tests" print this:

```
Testing started at 13:18 ...
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-lg_e610-LGOTMS79a92e5a
Uploading files
local path: /home/francesco/goak/out/production/www/www.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/io.cordova.goak
Installing io.cordova.goak
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/io.cordova.goak"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/io.cordova.goak
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

In "Event Log" this: 12:51:24 Error running All Tests:

```
Target package is not specified in AndroidManifest.xml
```

I do not understand how to solve. Here is the code in "AndroidManifest.xml":

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<Manifest xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package = "io.cordova.goak">
    <Uses-sdk android: minSdkVersion = "21" />
    <Application android: icon = "@ drawable / icon" android: label = "@ string / app_name"> </ application>
</ Manifest>
```

What I realized is that does not accept the package (use the default of Cordova). While running the shell command, which suggests to me, gives me this other error:

```
"root@francesco:/home/francesco/goak/goak# pm install -r /data/local/tmp/io.cordova.goak 
pm: could not connect to address 127.0.0.1:10101
root@francesco:/home/francesco/goak/goak#"
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] is caused by using lower sdk version device which is specified in your manifest. try to use API v21 devices. or change minSdkVersion = "21" to minSdkVersion = "15"

Comment: Now the error is this: Testing started at 14.56 ...
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-lg_e610-LGOTMS79a92e5a
Uploading file
 local path: /home/francesco/goak/out/production/www/www.apk
 remote path: /data/local/tmp/io.cordova.goak
Installing io.cordova.goak
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/io.cordova.goak"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/io.cordova.goak
Success
Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{io.cordova.goak/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
Empty test suite.